# Помогите разобраться с Count и List

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Помогите плз разобраться с задачкой.

Дано:

> Список костей ноги. Необходимо сделать итерацию списка и найти
>   совпадения введенного слова со словом в списке. Две попытки и
>   немедленный ответ после каждой из них. Кроме того, надо посчитать
>   сколько в списке пунктов.

Вот то что нарожал я (не могу никак сделать общее число):

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform",
         "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]
total = 0
guess = ""
def bones_func (guess, foot_bones, total):
guess = input ("Enter the name of the foot bone: ")
for bone in foot_bones:
    if guess.lower()== bone:
        print ("Correct")
        total += foot_bones.count(bone)
    else:
        print ("Incorrect")
        total += foot_bones.count(bone)

bones_func (guess, foot_bones, total)
bones_func (guess, foot_bones, total)
print (total)
```

А вот то, что я нашел на просторах интернета и что совсем загнало меня в ступор:

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]

def foot_bones_quiz(guess, answer):
total_bones = 0
for bones in answer:
    total_bones += bones.count(bones)
    if guess.lower() == bones.lower():
        return True
    else:
        pass
return False
print("Total number of identified bones: " + str(total_bones))

user_guess = input("Enter a bone: ")
print("Is " + user_guess.lower() + " a foot bone?" , foot_bones_quiz(user_guess, foot_bones))
user_guess = input("Enter another bone: ")
print("Is " + user_guess.lower() + " a foot bone?", foot_bones_quiz(user_guess, foot_bones))
```

Мне не понятно, откуда в решении есть переменная guess?  Как они связаны с user_guess? Как переменная answer связывается с foot_bones? Как сделать полный подсчет в списке?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне не понятно, откуда в решении есть переменная guess?

Описание функции `def foot_bones_quiz(guess, answer):` переменная `guess` – параметр функции.

---

> Как они связаны с user_guess? Как переменная answer связывается с foot_bones?

Тут функция вызывается `foot_bones_quiz(user_guess, foot_bones)` и в параметр `guess` попадет `user_guess`, а в `answer` – переменная `foot_bones`

---

> Как сделать полный подсчет в списке?

У списка есть метод `count`. Нужно название кости засунуть в count и получить результат.

Пример:

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]

bone = 'lateral cuneiform'
print(foot_bones.count(bone))  # 1
```

---

**PS.** я не медик, поэтому не знаю являются ли `"lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"` костями по отдельности или поиск должен находить  и по частичному совпадению, типо:

```
print(find_bones(foot_bones, 'cuneiform'))  # 3
```

---

**PPS.** если у вас задание именно вручную написать функцию поиска, тогда нужно знать: `функции`, `условия` и `циклы`.

```
def count_bones(bone_list, target_bone):
    # Для регистронезависимого поиска
    target_bone = target_bone.lower()

    number = 0

    for bone in bone_list:
        # Элементы списка тоже приводятся в тот же регистр, что target_bone
        if bone.lower() == target_bone:
            number += 1

    return number


foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]
print(count_bones(foot_bones, 'cuboid'))  # 1
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что если я создаю функцию def example (x, y),  то потом обращаясь к ней к примеру example (m,n), переменная m заменит x, а n заменит y? То есть можно подставлять не только значения, но и другие переменные?

Comment: @AntonZubochenko, верно.